# Can we do resumable upload in google cloud storage using signed URL?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I want to implement signed URL for resumable upload in GCS, But the problem is while I use Signed URl, which type of http method(PUT,POST,GET..) need to use for create "uploadId", and what url I have to use for this and same question for while getting "uploadId" with url in resumable upload.

I have gone through the tutorial with oAuth token, but I want to do via Signed URL Only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the note on the [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) section of the documentation:

> Note: If your users are only uploading resources (writing) to an access-controlled bucket, you can use the resumable uploads functionality of Google Cloud Storage, and avoid signing URLs or requiring a Google account. In a resumable upload scenario, your (server-side) code authenticates and initiates an upload to Google Cloud Storage without actually uploading any data. The initiation request returns an upload ID, which can then be used in a client request to upload the data. The client request does not need to be signed because the upload ID, in effect, acts as an authentication token. If you choose this path, be sure to transmit the upload ID over HTTPS.

Comment: Good tip, though it links like the quoted section is no longer present in the linked doc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use signed URLs. The initial call to begin the resumable upload (the POST) needs to be signed, and the remaining calls do not need a signature, just the upload ID.

Alternatively, as jterrace suggested, you could make the initial POST from the server and pass the upload ID to the client.

Comment: Thanks.. , Now I am getting uploadId url, But when I hit this url for single upload it works, but when I try to upload file in block, it gives error - "Bad request, please check with your software provider."